# Android Studio throws 'error: failed linking file resources'

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, xml-drawable

I was making an icon pack for my own phone. I was done with all the required icons. After a few days, I installed more apps and had to create icons for those too. I created, and imported all the icons in the drawable folder but suddenly, Android Studio starting throwing the error: `error: failed linking file resources.`

This is the actual error:

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\Hrishikesh\Documents\Android\Projects\Icons\app\src\main\res\layout\icon_picker.xml:15: error: resource drawable/grid_selector (aka com.kh.icons:drawable/grid_selector) not found.
C:\Users\Hrishikesh\Documents\Android\Projects\Icons\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml:5: error: resource drawable/unicon (aka com.kh.icons:drawable/unicon) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

But, I have both the files in the drawable folder. The grid_selector as well as unicon. Android Studio even shows them, is able to open them, etc. Also, the files in which these files are linked (like, the icon_picker.xml) aren't giving any errors. This error only comes up when I run the app to test on my phone.

What do I do?

[image: gird_selector.xml is present in drawable folder]

[image: Android Studio doesn't give any error in grid_selector.xml]

[image: Android Studio doesn't give any error in icon_picker.xml]

Comment: Is this "com.kh.icons" package from your package or from other repository ?. Also you could clean project and then invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: It is my package. I've built it from scratch. I'll try cleaning soon and update it here.

Comment: @twenk11k Tried the caches, still no luck.

Comment: @Hrishikesh Kokate  Remove mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher and try to add drawable file in IconPicker Imageview.

Comment: I've kept only mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml as my app's icon. Without that file, I'm getting error in AndroidManifest.xml. Also, which drawable are you talking about in your second sentence?